# События в Access

Tags: access, vba, события

Можно ли без использования каких-либо форм, использовать события?

Например, при редактировании таблицы пользователь переходит на новую строчку и срабатывает какое-то событие.

Answer (score 1):

В Акцессе, начиная с версии 2010 появились Data Macro - макросы, которые можно повесить на события именно в таблице: изменение данных, добавление или удаление строки. Из них в принципе можно вызвать функцию на VBA, например, через SetValue или IF